# How to trigger input from mobile number field clipboard on OTP auto input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi-input field which accepts 6 digits and moves to next field based on input from the previous.
The paste functionality was not functioning correctly for this, ie, only first field was getting filled so I added a paste event handler which handles the paste functionality using jQuery.

Code for handling paste:

```
$("#otp-container #first").on("paste", function(event){
  const clipboardData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  if(clipboardData){
    const pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
    const splittedOTP = pastedText.substring(0, 6).split("");
    const otpFieldids = ["#first","#second","#third","#fourth","#fifth","#sixth"];
    let isValidOTP = true;

    for (let i = 0; i < splittedOTP.length; i++) {
      if (!LoginHelper.prototype.checkIfInputIsNumber(splittedOTP[i].toString())) {
        isValidOTP = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isValidOTP) {
      event.preventDefault();
      for (let i = 0; i < otpFieldids.length; i++) {
        const element = $(`#otp-container ${otpFieldids[i]}`)
        if (element) {
          element.val(splittedOTP[i]);
        }
      }
      $(`#otp-container ${otpFieldids[splittedOTP.length-1]}`).select();
    }
  }

});
```

This is working correctly when user manually pastes the OTP but when user login from mobile phone and clicks on the clipboard autofill functionality is not working correctly. I assumed it might be calling the paste event handler but is not. The paste event handler is not getting triggered.

[image]

Is there any way to trigger this event?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by triggering the onInput method of first input as:

```
<input type="number" id="first" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" autocomplete="off" data-next="second" oninput="javascript: handleOTPPaste(this.value);" />
```

And filling other input boxes if the input length is greater than 1 on first input box,

```
   handleOTPPaste(OTPInput){
    if(OTPInput && OTPInput.length > 1){
        const splittedOTP = OTPInput.substring(0, 6).split("");
        const otpFieldids = ["#first","#second","#third","#fourth","#fifth","#sixth"];
        let isValidOTP = true;
    
        for (let i = 0; i < splittedOTP.length; i++) {
            if (!checkIfInputIsNumber(splittedOTP[i].toString())) {
                isValidOTP = false; 
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isValidOTP) {
            OTPInput.preventDefault();
            for (let i = 0; i < otpFieldids.length; i++) {
                const element = $(`#otp-container ${otpFieldids[i]}`)
                if (element) {
                element.val(splittedOTP[i]);
                }
            }
            $(`#otp-container ${otpFieldids[splittedOTP.length-1]}`).select();
        }
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular the problem is because of the `maxlength="1"` on first input
so you can solve it like this:

1. Set the max-length of first input equal to your the number of your inputs
2. Set an input event on your first input tag and call `handleOTPPaste($event)` which event.target.value gives you the full otp code
   3.To prevent filling the first input with all 6 digits you cab use `event.stopPropagation()` and fill the inputs like manually pasted code

So the first input will be like this:(for example the otp length is 6)

```
<input type="number" id="first" maxlength="6" pattern="\d*" autocomplete="off" data-next="second" (input)="handleOTPPaste($event);" />
```